# Is shortcircuit evaluation a good practice to replace if statements that seem trivial?

Tags: c

Let's say for example that you have a code that checks if a "boolean" flag is true to run some procedure, like this:

```
if( my_flag ){
 doStuff();
}
```

I could write it using a short-circuit evaluation, this is taking in account that the result from the evaluation has no value to the rest of the code, it could be written like:

```
my_flag && doStuff();
```

I have seen professional code written like this, from my perspective it improves readability removing innecesary syntax, but I have no idea if this is a good practice or not because I have also seen a lot of code written using the `if` statement.

I would like to know if theres something that I'm not taking in account or arguments against its use in **trivial** cases.

Comment: This is somewhat opinion-based, but I see the second case as *terrible* style. If you're using the result of the `&&`  for something, then yes, it makes sense to do that. But if it's just an isolated expression with a result that isn't used, then the second example is just hiding control flow.

Comment: No, the result of the evaulation is not meant to be used, it doesnt matter to the rest of the code. It's merely for conditional porpuses.

Comment: I wouldn't do it, for me logical expression are always side-effect free.

Comment: @marco-a What could be a possible side effect?

Comment: For very terse `if` statements that will “flow” for the reader, you could simply write `if (my_flag) doStuff();` on one line.

Comment: `doStuff();` is a function call that could possibly do stuff like writing to files, talking to some services via the internet, I don't know. Point being, I personally try to avoid statements like `my_flag && doStuff()` because it's not clear what `doStuff()` will actually do. (a simple logical expression will never have a side effect because it's just a check)

Comment: Someone's going to close this because it's asking for an opinion, and that's usually not supported. But NOOOOOO.... Don't do that.

Comment: Also, unrelated to my first argument, but: you're relying on the reader knowing what short-circuit evaluations are and how they work.

Comment: Personally, I find that trying to be too clever can backfire. If you accidentally type `my_flag & doStuff()` then assuming you don't get a type mismatch error, you have a bug that the function is called when it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Gene I hope not, im asking a question that can be answered by facts, opinions would not be usefull for me. I really want an objective answer. Actually I have found some of them here in the comments.

Comment: If you really hate the extra kruft, you can always one-line it without braces as just `if (my_flag) doStuff();` Only barely longer, doesn't depend on `doStuff` having a return value, and doesn't imply you really care about the return value when you don't.

Comment: Second option works wonder when `my_flag` is a pointer used in the parameter list of `doStuff ()` and you are coupling the logic tighter so nobody will copy this line somewhere else (at 2 am) forgetting that the check for the parameter is caller's responsibility. Also good when there are several functions being conditionally called with unique flags so the gain of being succinct becomes more significant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is shortcircuit evaluation a good practice to replace if statements that seem trivial?

- Not an option when `doStuff();` returns `void`.
- Obliges `doStuff();` to return a value now and in the future.

When competing options exist, code for maintenance and clarity.

Winner here:

```
if (my_flag) {
  doStuff();
}
```

If the `if` statement is short, optionally omit the braces

```
if (my_flag)
  doStuff();
```

Comment: _Not an option when doStuff(); returns void._ Could you explain this further?

Comment: @FranAcuna If at some point, it's decided that `doStuff` doesn't need to return a value, it's return type could be changed to `void`, in which case it *can't* be used as an operand to `&&`.

Comment: FranAcuna, If `doStuff();` returns `void`, `my_flag && doStuff();` is not valid code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh you are right!